# How to filter based on string while disregarding the number in it using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter, match

I have a list of columns that I want to filter, right now I'm using this logic:

```
for (const columnName of this.columnNames) {
   const matchingColumns = fieldsForSearch.filter(c => columnName === c || 
   columnName.match(c + '[ ][0-9]*$'));
   if (matchingColumns && matchingColumns.length > 0) {
      // do something...
   }
}
```

This is working fine, however, when I have a huge array it's taking a lot of time, especially the `.match` How can I make it faster? Using `.test` or maybe `.startsWith`?

The `this.columnNames` I'm filtering on can have values like `Color`, `Color 1`, `Color 2`, etc. This is why I have the logic:

```
columnName.match(c + '[ ][0-9]*$'))
```

It can also have values like this: `Age Range`, `Age Range Minimum`, `Age Range Maximum`.

What I want is to filter the name and the number, so in my code above Color, Color 1... passes but `Age Range Minimum` doesn't.

Sample input:

```
['Color', 'Color 1', 'Color 2', 'Color 3', 'Age Range', 'Age Range Minimum', 'Age Range Maximum']
```

Sample output:

```
['Color', 'Color 1', 'Color 2', 'Color 3']
```

Comment: @Fadi how much data you are trying to filter and do you are trying it on frontend or backend with nodejs?

Comment: A couple of thousand records, backend in nodejs

Comment: Confusing but `'(?<=Color)[ ][0-9]*$'`

Comment: @PeterSeliger - can't achieve the goal without RegExp anyway after rereading Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the OP's use case a valid approach was to use a regex which will match any string wich is a sequence of whitespace separated non digit characters only. Something like ... [`/^(?:\D+\s+\D+)(?:\s+\D+)*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/6EBe7U/1/) ... Thus one matches exactly those strings, the OP wants to reject. A filter function then uses the negated return value of [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) ...

```js
const sampleInput = ['Color', 'Color 1', 'Color 2', 'Color 3', 'Age Range', 'Age Range Minimum', 'Age Range Maximum'];
const expectedResult = ['Color', 'Color 1', 'Color 2', 'Color 3'];

// matches any string wich is a sequence of
// whitespace separated non digit characters.
// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/6EBe7U/1/]
const regXWsSeparatedNonDigitSequence = (/^(?:\D+\s+\D+)(?:\s+\D+)*$/);

console.log(
  sampleInput, ' =>',
  sampleInput.filter(item =>
    !regXWsSeparatedNonDigitSequence.test(item)
  )
);
console.log(
  'test passed ?',
  sampleInput.filter(item =>

    !regXWsSeparatedNonDigitSequence.test(item)

  ).join(',') === expectedResult.join(',')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

btw ... regex performance is not an issue at all.

The next test which filters two times 70,000 entries does prove it (two time less than 7msec) ...

```js
const regXWsSeparatedNonDigitSequence = (/^(?:\D+\s+\D+)(?:\s+\D+)*$/);

let testData = new Array(10_000);
let result;

// create an array of 70_000 string entries (10_000 x 7(string item count))
testData = testData
  .fill(['Color', 'Color 1', 'Color 2', 'Color 3', 'Age Range', 'Age Range Minimum', 'Age Range Maximum'])
  .flat(1);

// test with regex reference.
console.time("70,000 regX tests (reference) :: filter duration");

result = testData.filter(item =>
  !regXWsSeparatedNonDigitSequence.test(item)
)
console.timeEnd("70,000 regX tests (reference) :: filter duration");

console.log('test passed ?.. ', (result.length === 40_000));

// test with regex literal.
console.time("70,000 regX tests (literal) :: filter duration");

result = testData.filter(item =>
  !(/^(?:\D+\s+\D+)(?:\s+\D+)*$/).test(item)
)
console.timeEnd("70,000 regX tests (literal) :: filter duration");

console.log('test passed ?.. ', (result.length === 40_000));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Fadi ... regarding the above provided approach, are there any questions left?

Comment: Sorry wasn't getting any notifications on this post, thanks for your solution